# Case ... in, file type cases

Tags: bash, files, case

I was given homework where I need to test if `$1` is a file, special file or a folder in a **Case `$1` In statement**.

I tried some things but wasn't able to make it work. Do you have any idea on how to implement this (in a case statement)

What I need to achieve is :

```
if [ -f $1 ]
then
    exit 1
elif [ -d $1 ]
then
    exit 2
elif [ -c $1 -o -b $1 ]
then
    exit 3
else
    exit 0
fi
```

I'm not asking for the final code, just a way to make the following work:

```
Case $1 in
    -d) ...
```

Comment: Your `if`-based code seems like the most straightforward idea (although you should quote variables: `"$1"`; it seems strange for the exercise to require otherwise.

Comment: I can't really see a good way. Are you quite sure you're not supposed to do it with `stat`, which amongst others, can also output the file type? (`stat --format '%F' yourfile`)

Comment: Stat seems to be the right path to take but I have another question. I'm used to english distros but I'm in France and some professors use french distros, sometimes language prevents scripts from working based on the output of some binaries. In brief : is there a way to have a standard output with stat (like a INT or something) and not depend on the language to write conditions ?

Comment: Use `LC_ALL=C stat` but please ask separate questions in separate posts and not in the comments.

Answer (score 3):

Since the `if`-based code you posted seems simple enough, the
requirement to use a `case` construct is a bit strange. I suppose one
could retrieve the file type information that `ls -l` provides:

```
case "$(ls -ld -- "$1")" in
    -*) echo 'Regular file' ;;
    d*) echo 'Directory' ;;
    *)  echo 'other' ;;
esac
```

Comment: This would be a solution but it's a bit more "artisanal" than the stat method. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution I chose :

```
filetype=$(stat -c%F "$1")
exitcode=$?

if [ $exitcode -eq 0 ]
then
    case "$filetype" in
        "regular file") exit 1;;
        "directory") exit 2;;
        *) exit 3;;
    esac
else
    exit 0
fi
```

It still displays an error when stat fails (file does not exist) but it works fine. Thanks

Comment: That assumes GNU `stat`, a US-English locale, that `$1` doesn't start with `-` and that `$IFS` doesn't contain digits.

Comment: you could use `case $(file -- "$1") in ...`